# Is there a "grafana.net" that is different to "grafana"

Tags: grafana

Someone told me i should have a look at grafana.net? What is this? Is this something different than grafana?

I already checked google and asked other guys, no one has a clue what "grafana.net" could be (different than grafana) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a "reference" for Grafana portal (old domain was `grafana.net`, current one is [grafana.com](https://grafana.com)), where Grafana Labs (vendor of Grafana) has space for their users/customers. For example users can publish their [dashboards](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/), developers their [plugins](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/), etc.